# Parsing through DOM get all children and values

Tags: javascript, dom, recursion

Container is a div i've added some basic HTML to.

The debug_log function is printing the following:

> I'm in a span! 
>   I'm in a div! 
>   I'm in a 
>   p

What happened to the rest of the text in the p tag ("aragraph tag!!"). I think I don't understand how exactly to walk through the document tree. I need a function that will parse the entire document tree and return all of the elements and their values.  The code below is sort of a first crack at just getting all of the values displayed.

```
    container.innerHTML = '<span>I\'m in a span! </span><div> I\'m in a div! </div><p>I\'m in a <span>p</span>aragraph tag!!</p>';

    DEMO.parse_dom(container);



   DEMO.parse_dom = function(ele)
    {
        var child_arr = ele.childNodes;

        for(var i = 0; i < child_arr.length; i++)
        {
            debug_log(child_arr[i].firstChild.nodeValue);
            DEMO.parse_dom(child_arr[i]);
        }
     }
```

Comment: Are you just looking for the DOM versions of these elements/nodes or the HTML representation of them?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Generally when traversing the DOM, you want to specify a start point. From there, check if the start point has `childNodes`. If it does, loop through them and recurse the function if they too have `childNodes`.

Here's some code that outputs to the console using the DOM form of these nodes (I used the document/HTML element as a start point). You'll need to run an if against `window.console` if you're allowing non-developers to load this page/code and using `console`:

```
recurseDomChildren(document.documentElement, true);

function recurseDomChildren(start, output)
{
    var nodes;
    if(start.childNodes)
    {
        nodes = start.childNodes;
        loopNodeChildren(nodes, output);
    }
}

function loopNodeChildren(nodes, output)
{
    var node;
    for(var i=0;i<nodes.length;i++)
    {
        node = nodes[i];
        if(output)
        {
            outputNode(node);
        }
        if(node.childNodes)
        {
            recurseDomChildren(node, output);
        }
    }
}

function outputNode(node)
{
    var whitespace = /^\s+$/g;
    if(node.nodeType === 1)
    {
        console.log("element: " + node.tagName);  
    }else if(node.nodeType === 3)
    {
        //clear whitespace text nodes
        node.data = node.data.replace(whitespace, "");
        if(node.data)
        {
            console.log("text: " + node.data); 
        }  
    }  
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/ee5X6/

Answer (score 0):

In

```
<p>I\'m in a <span>p</span>aragraph tag!!</p>
```

you request the first child, which is the text node containing "I\'m in a".
The text "aragraph tag!!" is the third child, which is not logged.

Curiously, the last line containing "p" should never occur, because the span element is not a direct child of container.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it is what you need or if it is possible in your environment but jQuery can accomplish something similar quite easily. Here is a quick jQuery example that might work.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="INCLUDE JQUERY HERE">
</script>
</head>
<body>
<span>
<span>I\'m in a span! </span><div> I\'m in a div! </div><p>I\'m in a <span>p</span>aragraph tag!!</p>
</span>
<script>
function traverse(elem){
  $(elem).children().each(function(i,e){
    console.log($(e).text());
    traverse($(e));
  });
}

traverse($("body").children().first());
</script>
</body>
<html>
```

Which gives the following console output:

```
I\'m in a span! 
I\'m in a div! 
I\'m in a paragraph tag!!
p
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't take the `\\`'s out when I copied your example.

Comment: There's really no need for jQuery here.